# How to play vertical video in mobile fullscreen that will take up the whole screen using html5 just like youtube?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a vertical video, the aspect ratio is 1080x1920.
If I play it in fullscreen mode using video tag it does not take the whole mobile screen just like youtube.

```
<video controls>
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src='video.mp4' width='300px'></embed>
```

Using embed tags instead of videos tags should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with the aspect ratio of my video. I have set it to 16:9 and now have corrected it to 9:16 using Davinci Resolve. Now when I load it on my site the vertical fullscreen of the video tag now works.